# Spit an alphanumeric column into two columns on alpha or special characters

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, split

I'm creating a new database for a project from an old project which requires a SKU. The SKU is assigned by the government, however, clients - in order to avoid having to register a new product (it takes months) will take an existing sku - and add various randomness after the sku assigned
so for example:

- ASSIGNED SKU: 12345
- CLIENT DEFINED SKU: 12345ABC, or 12345-Oktoberfest, or 12345-123, or 12345.123, or 12345_Oktoberfest-123

there is no way to know what they'll do because the original design of the application was (at best description) remedial...

so I'm pulling in the column marked "sku" and was thinking, huh, ok, so splitting it if I knew the character to split on could be dealt with easily enough for:

```
SKU: 12345
extended_sku: ABC
```

primarily because I've been reading for a solution on stackoverflow and there are some really good examples, but for randomness there isn't really an example, and i suck at regex.

So I need to know how to go about testing the string value (it's a varchar field) and then splitting it into SKU bigint peeling off anything not numeric, and inserting that extended_sku into the 2nd table (for normalization) with the parsed off string after the numeric sku...

There is no way to determine the sku length, however, it will always be numeric.

So basically I need to test for anything after the numeric ends

This will be for postgresql 9.5 from a XLSX import which I'm currently pulling into a temp_table to properly format the data (because again, everything is a varchar field - including the pk heh)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the client generated sku is always an extension of the original sku, would  not `client sku - original sku` string not give you the newly created sku you want, so you can store it in a separate field ? For instance - original sku: `725AB1` - client sku: `725AB1_-1-_`  -> newly created sku: `725AB1_-1-_`  - `725AB1 = _-1-_`  (the minus operation here needs implementation).

Something like

1. Search for the original string in the client generated one
2. Add the original string length to the index where the original string was found in the client one
3. get the client string substring that starts at the index calculated in step 2, till the end of the string.

Comment: well actually this is database conversion, because I'm taking the existing database, and exporting it's data into a new properly designed database, so the user won't be able to just vomit items into the new db :)  If they want to extend a sku, they'll have to select from an existing sku because really the extended_sku is a batch version of that sku, not a random sku - which is what they're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the solution is:

```
SELECT 
    substring(sku from '(([0-9]+.*)*[0-9]+)') AS sku, 
    substring(sku from '(([A-Za-z]+.*)*[A-Za-z]+)')  AS extended,
    sku AS original_sku
FROM catalogue 
WHERE sku !~ '^[A-Za-z]+$';
```

@Veverke

worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
SELECT 
    substring(sku from '[0-9]+') AS sku,
    regexp_replace(sku, '^[0-9]+(.*)$', '\1') AS extended_sku, 
    sku AS original_sku
FROM products
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e5660/10)